# Maximum time-to-exit of random walk in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: probability-theory, optimization, stochastic-processes, random-walk

I am trying to solve the following problem :
Given a set $A$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and a point $p$ , I want to find a convex subset of $A$, call it $C$, such that $p$ is in $C$ and random walk starting at $p$ will have the maximum time-to-exit from $C$ (time-to-exit is the expected value of r.v. $X$ = number of time steps till random walk left $C$).

Any sources, ideas, directions will be helpful.

This is not h.w - the solution for that problem is relevant for my research. I didn't find any articles (or other sources) which deal with this problem. I tried to find such $C$ by myself but couldn't get any satisfied results.

Comment: There are lots of different ways to define a random walk on $\mathbb{R}^n$.  What do you have in mind?  And what is known about the set $A$?  (An arbitrary set $A$ might not have any nontrivial convex subsets at all.)

Comment: About A - my first step is a set A such that A's complement is convex. I hope that I will be able to say something about an arbitrary set (like properties that C has to satisfy). About the definition of the random walk - I used that definition : http://www.dartmouth.edu/~chance/teaching_aids/books_articles/probability_book/Chapter12.pdf , but it doesn't matter (I can "adapt" my research to a different definition ) - any result with different definition will be helpful as well

Comment: So if your random walk is just a sum of iid rvs in $\Bbb R^n$, unless their distribution is concetrated at $0$, they will leave any bounded set with probability $1$, and with finite exit time - is that what you are looking for?

Comment: A doesn't have to be bounded , and even if it is - I am looking for a C that will maximize the number of steps to leave it

Comment: So even if random walk will eventually leave every C (which is not necessarily true because C may not be bounded ) - I am looking for the C which maximize the number of steps to leave it of a random walk

Comment: I see, indeed $C$ may not be bounded and so that exit time may be infinite. How would you expect the answer to look like? I am not sure that given a distribution of $X_i$ and $A,p$ you can get an analytical expression for $C$. If $A$ is nice enough, I would go for the convex set in the direction of $\Bbb E X_i$ since there we have the fastest exit.

Comment: In the first case (A's complement is convex) I assume that C will be an half plan (let d be the closest point to p in A's complement. The line through p and d creates half plan. I think that's the optimal C in that case, but I have no idea how to prove it or if that's true  )